# Cannot deserialize ErrorResponseException from Spring 6 / SpringBoot 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have created a `@RestControllerAdvice` that handles all ErrorResponseExceptions (including my own class `NtErrorResponseException` that extends ErrorResponseException).

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class NtExceptionHandling extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(NtErrorResponseException.class)
    ProblemDetail handleBookmarkNotFoundException(NtErrorResponseException e) {
        return e.getBody();
    }
}
```

But when I try to test it using this test, I get the following error:

**Test**

```
@Test
    void problemTest(@Autowired TestRestTemplate restTemplate) {
        final ResponseEntity<ErrorResponseException> problem = restTemplate.getForEntity("/api/hello-world/problem", ErrorResponseException.class);
        assertThat(problem.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        assertThat(problem.getBody()).isNotNull();
    }
```

**Error**

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.springframework.web.ErrorResponseException]

(...)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.ErrorResponseException` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): Throwable needs a default constructor, a single-String-arg constructor; or explicit @JsonCreator
 (...)
```

The error in question is **Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.web.ErrorResponseException` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): Throwable needs a default constructor, a single-String-arg constructor; or explicit @JsonCreator** which makes sense as the `ErrorResponseException` does not have a default constructor, but how am I supposed to test this when it does not have it? I was hoping that Spring had made the ErrorResponseException class easily deserializable?

What would be a good way for me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The deserialized object that Spring Boot returns from the controller is not a `ErrorResponseException` but rather a `ProblemDetail`.

Fix:

```
@Test
void problemTest(@Autowired TestRestTemplate restTemplate) {
    final ResponseEntity<ProblemDetail> problem = restTemplate.getForEntity("/api/hello-world/problem", ProblemDetail.class);
    assertThat(problem.getStatusCode().value()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    assertThat(problem.getBody()).isNotNull();
}
```